# Swift action movement and 5-foot step

Tags: dnd-3.5e, movement, actions

I realize swift actions came out after the PHB was printed, but how can we reconcile them with this part from the PHB:

> If you move **no actual distance** in a round (commonly because you have swapped your move for one or more equivalent actions, such as standing up), you can take one 5-foot step either before, during, or after the action. - page 138

So if I have the Travel Devotion feat or the Sudden Leap maneuver, can I both move an actual distance (swift action) and use a 5-foot step?

I guess this was addressed in one of the later publications, but where?

Comment: @HeyICanChan they are different enough that I do not feel bad about not finding them, but they answer my question. Close this as a duplicate